# Парсинг json файлов c++

Tags: c++, json, поиск-библиотек

Каким образом я могу парсить файл json?

Comment: Если Вы "не шарите" как решить задачу, то попробуйте хотя бы научится сформулировать задачу. Ну а потом freelancer.com или подобные.

Answer (score 3):

Используй библиотеку https://github.com/nlohmann/json/tree/develop/test или подобную

Comment: А json5 оно умеет?

Comment: @vp_arth https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/150